# Multiple 'sed' commands with 'for' loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

I want to replace several strings in several documents. I know how to combine `sed` commands using the `-e` option but I don't know how to combine them in a script to run it on multiple files.

I tried to use the 'for' loop but it didn't work.

```
for i in `ls *.txt`; do sed -e 's/22/twenty two/g' \ -e 's/23/twenty three/g'$i > new/$i; done
```

Any idea how to do this with `shell`, `awk`, `Python` or `Perl`?

Comment: You could try a more generic approach: `sed 's/\<2/twenty /g;s/1\>/one/g;s/2\>/two/g;s/3\>/three/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"for" cycles usage may be dangerous when you work with "external" data: to be sure, try to create a .txt file with space in its name.

And yes, you dont need '-e' sed option at all, just combine commands with the simple ";":

```
while read -r f; do
 sed 's/22/twenty two/g; s/23/twenty three/g' "$f" > new/"$f"
done < <(ls *.txt)
```

You can just use sed "in-place" file modification feature:

```
while read -r f; do
 sed -i 's/22/twenty two/g; s/23/twenty three/g' "$f"
done < <(ls *.txt)
```

Comment: will fail for file names that contain spaces. Never loop on or otherwise parse the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing:

```
for i in `ls *.txt`
do
   sed -e 's/22/twenty two/g' \ -e 's/23/twenty three/g'$i > new/$i
                              ^                       ^^^
                              why is this here?       missing space!
done
```

Which can be rewritten to:

```
for i in *.txt  # <-- no need to `ls`!!
do
   sed -e 's/22/twenty two/g' -e 's/23/twenty three/g' "$i" > new/"$i"
done
```

So your problems were:

- strange `\` in between commands.
- missing space between `sed 's...'` and the file name.

And a suggestion:

- do not use `ls`, just expand `*.txt`.

Comment: super duper fast :) +1

Comment: This should work too: `sed 's/22/twenty two/g;s/23/twenty three/g'`

Comment: True @Jotne ! `sed -e 's/hello/X/' -e 's/bye/Y/'` is equivalent to `sed 's/hello/X/;s/bye/Y/'` (without the `-e`). I prefer the former for visibility. Thanks for reminding about it!

Comment: Thanks Fedorqui for your very quick reply and @Jotne for your suggestion. Great! I put '\' because I use it when I combine 'sed' commands with 'cat'. I thought I'll need it here as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you use awk you don't need a loop

```
awk '{gsub(/22/,"twenty two");gsub(/23/,"twenty three");print > "new/"FILENAME}' *.txt
```

Comment: The order of evaluation to the right of a `>` is undefined so you need to always parenthesise any operations like string concatenation or you will get a syntax error on some awks. So it should be `print > ("new/"FILENAME)`. +1 for the right approach though.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of substitutions to do you might prefer something like:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    map[22] = "twenty two"
    map[23] = "twenty three"
}
{
    for (old in map)
        gsub("\\<" old "\\>", map[old])
    print > ("new/" FILENAME)
}
' *.txt
```

The word boundaries (I used GNU awk notation) are important so that `123` doesn't become `1twenty three`. That's a problem all the other solutions currently have.

Comment: Actually I do have about 20 substitutions so I will try this. Thanks, cheers.